# SQL Query Using Max Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following (example) table.  I'd like to get the PROJECT_NUMBER, TASK, TASK_DATE where TASK_DATE is the Max date/time.

So the query should return:
1, D001-Market Reg, 10/20/2017 1:36:16 PM

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Use TOP  combined with an ORDER

Comment: isn't task date on A001-Plant Confir - @ 11:45 PM and should be max, not D001 @ 1:36pm?

Comment: Twelfth, yeah - I had manually entered that date/time and intended it to be AM - didn't notice that until you pointed it out!  Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` and `top`:

```
select top 1 t.*
from example as t
order by task_date desc;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - this got me what I needed - much appreciated!